# Play! framework 1.2.5: How to test if response is secure?

Tags: java, testing, https, playframework-1.x

A test case for my contact formular page is to make sure it's always in a secure context respectively using SSL. Basically, all I want to know, is that I have a given request where `request.secure = true;`

The following response does not contain any information about this and its headers are empty:

```
@Test
public void shouldShowContactForm() {
    Response response = GET("/contact");
    // How can I ask the response, if the complete URL is in HTTPS?
}
```

Even if I explicitly set my own request, I cant see the right way to do this:

```
@Test
public void shouldShowContactFormInSSLContext() {
    Request request = newRequest();
    request.secure = true;
    Response response = GET(request, "/contact");
    // Is it now possible?
}
```

Is this even the right approach to test this or am I simply missing something important about the request/response?

Answer (score 2):

For this question I think what I've done for my apps in the past is have a @before interceptor on all my controllers that looks like this.

```
     @Before
     static void checkSSL(){
         if(Play.mode.equals(Play.Mode.PROD)){
             if(!request.secure) {
                 Router.ActionDefinition cashTicketDefinition = Router.reverse(request.controller + "." + request.actionMethod);
                 cashTicketDefinition.absolute();
                 String url = cashTicketDefinition.url.replaceFirst( "http:", "https:");

                 redirect(url, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly the problem, there is no 'response.secure' field. The only way to get this information from the response is to look into the header for the location, if it starts with "https". But the header for a simple GET call is empty.

Comment: @crasp - I think what you want to do is just enforce that every request is secure. I edited my post above to demonstrate.